# Che cosa vuol dire "farci basta"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> M’aiutava a tener duro la stagione, che era inverno, e se Dio voleva il lavoro non ammazzava piú e poi si passava quasi tutto il tempo al caldo nella stalla, tanto che **ci faceva basta** il mangiare che era ancora piú scarso che in tutte le altre epoche.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "ci faceva basta" in questo brano? Ho cercato alla voce "basta" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione. Significa "ci bastava, ci era sufficiente il mangiare"? Si tratta di un modo di dire piemontese?

Comment: _Ci faceva basta_ significa _ci bastava_, _ci facevamo bastare_ il mangiare.

Comment: “Che il cibo, nonostante fosse più scarso che in altre epoche, ci era sufficiente”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questo contesto **ci faceva basta** significa ci bastava, ci facevamo bastare il mangiare per arrivare a superare l’inverno, sebbene il cibo fosse assai scarso.

La vita contadina dell’epoca era molto legata alle stagioni.

In inverno c’era poco da fare perché nelle Langhe il clima rigido e la neve non permettevano coltivazioni.